# Is it idiomatic to say "grammatical and idiomatic"?

Tags: idiomatic-language

In my other post (["time adverbs" vs. "adverbs of time"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/239527/109190)) I use these two examples

> The word *already* is a kind of time adverbs.
>
> The word *already* is a kind of adverbs of time.

and suggest that both sentences are "**grammatical and idiomatic**".

I found lots of people also [use the expression a lot](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22grammatical%20and%20idiomatic%22).

Google Ngram might also justify that.

[image]

So, is it idiomatic to say "grammatical and idiomatic"?

Comment: Yes, but the sentences *aren't* "grammatical and idiomatic". The word **adverbs** should be the singular **adverb**.

Comment: Why do you think it is/isn't idiomatic?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the phrase, except that honestly, I've only seen it used on this SE site.

Comment: @pboss3010 I guess that's because native English speakers never care about if their expressions are idiomatic. Actually, what they say is idiomatic, right?

Comment: @WXJ96163 No, even people learning English I've met in real life generally ask "does that sound right?", "is that how you use it?" or something similar.

Comment: @pboss3010  "No, even people learning English ... ask" sounds the learners ask this kind of question a lot. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Grammatical" and "idiomatic" are two adjectives that may well be used together, but together are not necessarily an "idiomatic phrase", so be careful with what you label as "idiomatic". You say you have found "lots of people" saying "grammatical and idiomatic", so that really should indicate that it *is* both grammatical, *and* idiomatic in the sense that it sounds natural, but it is not really what you could call a "commonly used" phrase.

Also, be careful with your use of ngrams. They can be useful, they can also massively misrepresent a matter, especially when you represent something that *is* a true idiom and is commonly said against something that is perfectly grammatical but may not be said as often. To use an analogy, that is like comparing apples and oranges.

Look at [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=grammatical%20and%20idiomatic%2C%20idiomatic%20and%20grammatical&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgrammatical%20and%20idiomatic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cidiomatic%20and%20grammatical%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cgrammatical%20and%20idiomatic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cidiomatic%20and%20grammatical%3B%2Cc0) that measures "grammatical and idiomatic" against "idiomatic and grammatical". One way around is favoured more than the other, but both have been used. I would suggest that grammar is the *first* consideration because if something is not grammatically correct then it cannot be idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess I should have said "these sentences are both grammatical, and idiomatic", right?

Comment: @WXJ96163 It's fine and dandy to use two adjectives without a comma.

Comment: By "dandy", I guess you meant **handy**, right?

Comment: @WXJ96163 the [tools](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fine%20and%20dandy) are there for you to use ;)

Comment: @WXJ96163 I was answering with an example - an idiom with two adjectives and no comma.

Comment: @Astralbee I got it. Thank you. So, the key is the position of **both**, which means, "these sentences are **both** grammatical and idiomatic" sounds more natural than the one in my OP,  right?

Comment: @WXJ96163 Yes that's right.