# Is "are synonyms each other" a bit wordy?

Tags: word-usage

In one of my posts (["commonly used" vs "sound natural" and "is idiomatic"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/240234/109190)) I said

> Obviously, *idiomatic* and *natural* **are synonyms each other**.

In my native language, "**each other**" is for emphasizing in this kind of situation. However, I am not sure whether it conveys that information in English. So, I looked up Cambridge Dictionary, and got this example

> The words "small" and "little" are **synonyms**.

So, is "are synonyms **each other**" a bit wordy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**'Are synonyms each other'** is wordy as well as incorrect.

You could say 'small and little are synonyms **of** each other'. However, if you think it's wordy, you could also say 'small and little are synonymous'.

'Idiomatic and natural are synonyms of each other' -> 'idiomatic and natural are synonymous' -> 'idiomatic and natural are synonyms'.

I haven't seen 'each other' used to emphasise this kind of situations (as P.E says 'of each other' is redundant).

Comment: Thank you. Did you notice the example from Cambridge Dictionary?

Comment: No. Where's it?

Comment: My second example.

Comment: 'Small' and 'little' are synonymous. However, you cannot use them interchangeably in every situation. Which one to use depends on the context.

Comment: What I meant is "**synonymous**" and "**synonyms**", your example uses the former while the example from Cambridge Dictionary uses the latter.

Comment: They are both correct. Which one you use is a matter of choice. I would have used 'synonymous' rather than 'synonyms of each other'.
(**Note:** If you want to use *'synonymous'*, then don't say *'synonymous of each other'*. Just say *'they're synonymous'*.)

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I've got "synonymous" and  'synonyms of each other'. How about a simple "**synonyms**", just exactly the same as the example from Cambridge Dictionary?

Comment: Just **'synonyms'** is also correct.

Comment: Big and little are synonyms ... just not of each other. Big and little are synonyms of large and small respectively.

Comment: @CJ Dennis, it was just to answer OP's question. I suggested two simpler ways of saying that. I'd say 'synonymous' myself.

Comment: If I read "Small and little are synonyms.", I'd assume it was meant "of each other". However, some people choose to be overly picky. Personally, I'd say "synonyms" instead of "synonymous" because neither is particularly common, so I'd choose the simpler word. However, that doesn't mean anyone else should feel bound by that.

Comment: Right. I agree.

Comment: Are we certain that the OP understands that *synonymous* is an adjective?

Comment: It is redundant to say that two words are synonyms _of each other._

Comment: @P. E. Dant Reinstate Monica, Hello. Yes. But that's what OP had said. I have provided two alternatives. :)

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul The OP wonders whether the expression is "too wordy", but he doesn't mention redundancy, and his comments indicate that he may not realize that _synonymous_ is an adjective.

Comment: @P.E.DantReinstateMonica, You're welcome to edit my answer. :)